# User not allowed by policy conditions - Entra External ID for customers

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration, entra

I am using External ID for my customer tenant, authenticating via an Angular SPA.

My setup is identical to what is described in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/sample-single-page-app-angular-sign-in

I downloaded the [sample app provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/1-Authentication/2-sign-in-angular/SPA/src/app/auth-config.ts), replaced the auth config my details and attempted to login with a personal email account. I am able to create a new account inside the tenant but when the app attempts to retrieve a token the following error is returned.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS131010: User not allowed by policy conditions. Trace ID: b989b1cf-f73e-4d3e-b23e-a35907f50000 Correlation ID: 11dee46b-a316-4265-9a90-5810cd78f395 Timestamp: 2024-01-23 01:50:02Z",
    "error_codes": [
        131010
    ],
    "timestamp": "2024-01-23 01:50:02Z",
    "trace_id": "b989b1cf-f73e-4d3e-b23e-a35907f50000",
    "correlation_id": "11dee46b-a316-4265-9a90-5810cd78f395",
    "suberror": "bad_token"
}
```

I can also see the failed request in Entra. Not what to do at this point other than start from scratch and see if that resolves the issue. Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in that [sample pre-requisites](https://i.imgur.com/tTQNRMG.png), it won't work if you try to sign in with **personal** accounts. You need to create new user in that customer tenant and login with that user credentials. I got the token claims successfully when I login with user from that tenant https://i.imgur.com/QcQRaKr.png

Comment: Does that mean personal accounts (i.e. @ live.com, @ hotmail.com. @ outlook.com) are barred completely? That means MS is preventing their own customers from signing up with lcoal accounts in a customer tenant? I have a personal account with an @ outlook.com suffix. Until very recently I was able to create a local account in the customer tenant with that account. I have removed that account today and tried the sign-in flow, and I am getting the same error. Also, the user object will be deleted automatically from the Entra Users pane! :O

Comment: I tried signing up with another domain, https://www.disposablemail.com/, which led to the same error... either there is blacklist of disallowed domains that is documented exactly nowhere, or the error is something else. And again, the user is DELETED automatically from Entra, I.m not sure how I should feel about this